# Celery nested groups and chains don't work with concurrency 1. Works with concurrency 2

Tags: python, celery

```
(group(functionA.si(post.id), functionB.si(post.id) | group(functionC.si(post.id), functionD.si(post.id))) | functionE.si(post.id)).delay()
```

It hangs on functionC with concurrency 1 for some reason. New to Celery so not sure why this workflow won't work.

The culprit is the inner nested group with functionC and functionD.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.